# What will be the period of a state if it can go to either recurrent state or a state with a period N?

Tags: markov-process

Let's consider that I have a state 0 that goes in three directions: one leads to a recurrent state, and the other two go to different states with periods M and N. What will be the period of a state 0? Would be glad to see a detailed explanation.